# What are some cool or useful server/networking tricks?

Tags: untagged

For example:

Setting up a server as an secure HTTP proxy to use in a filtered internet connection.
Altering a computer's/network's DNS to reroute traffic.

What are some other fun and useful tricks you think we should all know about?

Comment: maybe this should be a wiki?

Answer (score 5):

## Screen

(linux & OS X/macports)

It allows console users to run any number of text-based applications, interactive command shells, curses-based applications, text editors etc, within a single terminal.

I barely started using it fluently, thanks to a few online tutorials out there: [**http://news.softpedia.com/news/GNU-Screen-Tutorial-44274.shtml**](http://news.softpedia.com/news/GNU-Screen-Tutorial-44274.shtml)

***Quick reference:***

- Start a new session: **#screen -S sessioname**
- **Ctrl+a d** to detach
- List running sessions: **#screen -ls**
- Connect to running session: **#screen -x sessioname**

There are some Pros here who might want to add to this post their useful commands for screen.

Here's another useful [**tutorial**](http://www.linuxforums.org/applications/the_screen_program.html)

Comment: there is also [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) which does similar job but better :)

Answer (score 5):

[Using your host file to send ad crap to localhost](http://www.mvps.org/winhelp2002/hosts.htm).

Comment: +1. I have always wondered if there was a performance penalty with this method. Never enough to stop me when I KNOW I wanted to block a certain URL or two. Adblock certainly does the trick well enough.

Comment: Windows 2000 (and XP before a certain SP level) would experience a performance hit on startup if you had a very large hosts file (such as on created by spybot) as the DNS client service processed the file inefficiently. Not a problem now as far as I kown, and there were workarounds then too (i.e. turn off the DNS client service).

Comment: blacklist the ads servers in the dns :D

Answer (score 4):

anycast - we use it for our DNS.

Comment: I admit I don't even know what that is? I thought I'd post it as a separate question:

http://serverfault.com/questions/14985/what-is-anycast-and-how-is-it-helpful

Answer (score 3):

[Upside-Down-Ternet](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pete/upside-down-ternet.html)

An excellent little trick to play on unsuspecting users. The "kitty war" intermediate idea too.

Comment: +1 kittenwar admin must be proud being chosen for this trick !

Answer (score 1):

ssh's various tunneling options

- -R forward port from remote host to/through the initiating end of the ssh session
- -L forward port from initiating host through the remote host
- -D ssh's socks-proxy

Answer (score 1):

mostly linux [ and possibly bsd ] relaed:

using [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/) in bridge mode to.. bridge remote ethernet segments. not efficient, but sometimes really helpful.

using netcat instead of ssh to transfer data **quickly** across secure local network.

using reverse proxy or DNAT combined with SNAT on multihomed host to make some services from network A available to clients in network B when you [ for some political reasons ] have no control over routing between A and B.

using [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) to block blind hammering of your ssh / ftp / http and possibly other services.

Comment: +1 for netcat. when they say it's the swiss-army knife for network, they're right.

Answer (score 0):

[Set up some magic in your ~/.ssh/config to do automagic jump host forwarding.](http://glandium.org/blog/?p=308) Lets you do things like `ssh login1%host1+login2%host2+host3` right from the command line without breaking flow to go set up a tunnel and remember the ProxyCommand syntax.

Answer (score 0):

clusterssh to execute commands easily on multiple server!