# Simple Anycast Howto?

Tags: dns-hosting, anycast

some DNS providers give me anycast, like:
http://web.easydns.com/DNS_hosting.php

Now what do i do to get it working?
1. Buy "DNS Hosting package" from them
2. Have some servers with the same IP around the globe

now what: How do i setup? Will ANY dedicated server from any Hosting Provider work with easyDNS to enable anycast. Or only some Hosting Providers do support anycast/easyDNS?

thank you

Comment: To me it looks like EasyDNS is saying their DNS servers (on which your domain will live) are anycasted, not that they will give you anycasted hosting service.  You may want to read http://serverfault.com/questions/14985/what-is-anycast-and-how-is-it-helpful if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

This has little to do with DNS; the package they offer you is their anycast network.

Your own anycast network involves getting your own PI IP's (while you still can) and having them announced (or announcing them yourself) over BGP at multiple locations. You will need a lot of networking knowledge, out of band network access etc..

Why do you think you need anycast?

Answer (score 1):

EasyDNS public facing resolvers are already 'ANYcasted'.

Depending on the "DNS Hosting Package" you buy from them
you can use them as 'slave only' or let them be the master
for your zones.

Either way you should get the benefit of their anycasted network.

Answer (score 0):

it's simple.
You have one public ip address wich refers all your client and many public\private ip address around the globe (your anycast network)