# Different name servers for different countries. Speed up DNS lookup time

Tags: domain-name-system, performance

Is it possible to create different NS for different countries?

For example, we have 4 nameservers:

```
#for US
ns1.us.domain.com
ns2.us.domain.com

#for Europe
ns1.europa.domain.com
ns2.europa.domain.com
```

DNS requests coming from Europe will go to `ns1.europa, ns2.europa` and requests from US and other world will go to `ns1.us, ns2.us`.

Maybe some paid DNS provides can do it?
Any other other ways to speedup DNS lookup?
Any links and advises are appreciated.

Comment: You mean like Anycast or Geocast?

Comment: @TheCleaner, sorry, but I have no clue what is Anycast and Geocast. Please, can you explain a little. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you understand first of all that DNS lookups are cached closer to the user anyway (so you're only talking about the initial lookup by an ISP resolver or similar - before they get your result cached)... the only way to do what you're asking is via Anycast as TheCleaner already eluded to.

Anycast is already explained in excellent detail here: [What is "anycast" and how is it helpful?](https://serverfault.com/questions/14985/what-is-anycast-and-how-is-it-helpful)

Answer (score 0):

If you subscribe to DNS services such as [Amazon's Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#How_Route_53_provides_high_availability_low_latency) or [Akamai](http://www.akamai.com/html/solutions/enhanced_dns.html), they will provide this type of service for you.

You have to understand that they will leverage their respective network infrastructure to do so...not the DNS protocol per say.