# Is IP Anycast helpful for fast loading website?

Tags: ip, website, anycast, loading

I'm not sure but before I purchase http://dnsmadeeasy.com IP anyast service I really need to know What is IP Anycast actually and how does this work? Can anyone explain in simple sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be marked as a duplicate as it really hits [this anycast question](https://serverfault.com/questions/14985/what-is-anycast-and-how-is-it-helpful) at a basic level.

Anycast is very common for DNS.  If you have a global presence, the first time someone accesses your website, they must resolve it with your DNS server.  If your DNS and website are both hosted in New York, for example, and someone from China wants to view your site.

They must make 2 requests to New York to see your site (1 to the DNS server, 1 to the web server).  Each of these requests can sometimes take almost a full second depending on location and network conditions.

If your DNS is hosted with a good anycast provider, the user will have a low latency request for the DNS information and then still have to pay the price for the long request to New York in my hypothetical scenario.

For most basic web presences, you probably don't care all that much.  But if you have a lot of global traffic, anycast can definitely speed things up for your users and ultimately give you more conversions and higher ROI.  It all depends on your needs.

Comment: You're awesome ! I was bit confused in on wiki's things but this one cleared the concepts. Thanks