# Create multiple custom nameservers on a single domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, nameserver

Our company domain is registered with Godaddy.com and we have 2 custom nameservers set up pointing at our server in Washington, which we use for our american websites.

```
ns1.ourCompany.com -> USA server
ns2.ourCompany.com -> USA server
```

We've recently hired a new VPS in Germany which we want to use for our European websites. Is it possible to configure a new set of nameservers on the same domain which will resolve to the EU server without having to hit the US server first?

```
ns3.ourCompany.com -> EU server
ns4.ourCompany.com -> EU server
```

Comment: Is anycast what you ended up doing?  When I read your question I interpret not that you want to re-route based on geolocation, but rather have your EU websites on the ns3/ns4 and don't want to route the request through ns1/ns2 to receive the DNS.  I am in a similar situation and was curious if you found a good solution?

Comment: No we didnt use anycast in the end. We ended up using our US server as a kind of DNS switchboard for our root domain. So the US server has simple DNS records for NS3/NS4 which just points at the EU server, where those nameservers reside. Not ideal but worked fine for us.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am basically doing now, but I am adding more servers to the mix and if anything were to happen to the one server, then the others would also be down.  Thanks for the update.

Comment: I didn't need email for my main domain(ourCompany.com in your example).  If you did, you would need to add additional host records on the server, but there is information [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/840304/multiple-nameservers-for-multiple-dedicated-servers-on-a-single-domain) to how I ended up solving this for my requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for that is to run an [anycast](https://serverfault.com/questions/14985/what-is-anycast-and-how-is-it-helpful) DNS service, which is not really a feasible solution for most small companies to manage for themselves.

Many registrars offer such anycast DNS services for their customers.

Comment: And those many registrars are so cheap it's really not worth doing it yourself unless you're a huge company. AWS's solution is $0.50/month for a domain. Typing up a SF post probably costs more in salary than the next few years of service.

Comment: Great thanks. I presume this is what Godaddy's "premium DNS" service is doing?

Comment: Yes, Godaddy is one such provider that offers anycast

Comment: @cronoklee Yes, but I'm dubious of the words "premium" and "GoDaddy" in the same sentence.

Comment: Ha ha Thanks guys. One last clarification: Anycast looks to be for auto-routing visitors to the best server but what I was asking about was about setting up new nameservers for each region and manually giving each website a different nameserver so that it points to only one (local) server. My question is really around how to create 2 sets of *unrelated* nameservers on a single domain, pointing at different servers. Is anycast still the best option for this?

Comment: @cronoklee That's getting into the realm of more complicated things. Some providers offer something like that - AWS Route53 allows you to [route visitors based on geolocation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo) - but you'd want replication between the various local servers (I'd be upset if my account went away because I flew from NYC to London).